# Call to undefined method App\UserShiftPattern::userWorkScheduleList()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to get name from other database table, and get this error method, which part did i missed?

```
public function userWorkScheduleList()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserShiftPattern::class,'id','user_id');
}


                 <tbody>
                    @foreach ($usps as $usp => $usplist)
                    <tr>
                            <td>{{ $usplist->userWorkScheduleList()->name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

Comment: did you try `$usplist->userWorkScheduleList->name`?

Comment: yes. and here the new error --> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/Projects/krono_lte2/resources/views/admin/usershiftpattern.blade.php)

Comment: are you sure that 'id ' and 'user_id' are correct and should not be reversed?